# Mongodb - count of items using addToSet

Tags: mongodb, count, sum, distinct

I grouped by `organization` and used `$addToSet` to show the distinct `machineIds` associated with that `organization`. I would like to get the count of `machineIds` for each `organization`. However the code below is returning a count of all `machineIds`, not the count of distinct ones. Is there another way to get the total unique `machineIds`?

```
db.getCollection('newcollections').aggregate([{
    $group: {
    _id: {
        organization: "$user.organization"
    },
    machineId: {
        "$addToSet": "$user.machineId"
    },
    count: {
        $sum: 1
    }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Can you show your document?

Comment: "_id" : {
                "organization" : ""
            },
            "machineId" : [ 
                ""
            ],
            "count" : 2.0000000000000000

Comment: this example only had one machineId but the count is 2

Comment: You can use `distinct` : 
 `db.collection.distinct("machineId").length;`

Comment: Still it is pretty unclear. Can u show sample document on which u are applying above given query?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("757676467467657990"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "time" : ISODate("2015-01-13T13:45:19.670Z"),
    "status" : “success",
    "user" : {
        "organization" : “XYZ Corp”,
        "machineId" : "xyz3889548564865",
    }
}

Answer (score 18):

You need to use [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator in projection like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
    _id: {
        organization: "$user.organization"
    },
    machineId: {
        "$addToSet": "$user.machineId"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "organization": "$_id.organization",
    "machineId": 1,
    "_id": 0,
    "size": {
        $size: "$machineId"
    }
    }
}])
```

Comment: I want to group result by area wise deler name name and get count of loan application status under him by setting limit of 50. If i do addtoset then it always returning application count 1